# Из базы надо вывести сортированном ввиде

Tags: php, сортировка, pdo, select

дорогие мегамозги!
Помогите, пожалуйста.
Мне необходимо вывести из базы клиентов сортированном ввиде (Картинка2)
 В корне проекта содержиться лишь 2 файла (index.php, db.php)

> index.php содержит следующий код:

```
<?php
  require_once "dev.php"; // для вывода ошибок внятном ввиде
  require_once "db.php"; // подключаемся на базу через PDO

  $sql = ("SELECT * FROM users_cash");
  $sth = $pdo->query($sql);
  $result = $sth->fetchAll();
  foreach($result as $row) {
    echo "<p>".$row['name']." ".$row['surname']." ".$row['val']." ".$row['summ']."<p>";
  }
```

> а db.php содержит следующий код:

```
<?php
    $host     = 'localhost';
    $dbname   = 'keremetbank';
    $user     = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $charset  = 'utf8';

    $sdn = "mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname; charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ]; 
    $pdo = new pdo($sdn, $user, $password);
```

> Это выводит мне вот такую запись (я на примере exel файле показываю):
>   [image: Картинка1]
>
> А мне необходимо вот такую запись получить:
>   [image: Картинка2]

То есть сортировать по валюте и по каждой валюте добавить **Итого:** и суммировать всех и тоже написать рядом а остальные поля должны быть пустыми.

Comment: Надо параметрический запрос делать.

Comment: самое простое для вас наверное будет отсортировать список, по мере вывода в ПХП считать сумму и тут же смотреть, если валюта сменилась, то выводим накопленную сумму, и обнуляем потом. Также можно решить и на уровне запроса к БД, например, с использование `group by with rollup` либо юнионн с суммированием/группировкой

Answer (score -1):

1. Выберем все валюты

   ```
   $sql = ("SELECT valuta FROM users_cash order by valuta");

   $sth = $pdo->query($sql);
   $valuta = $sth->fetchAll();
   ```
2. Для каждой валюты выберем все вхождения и подсчитаем сумму

   ```
   foreach($valuta as $val) {           
     $sql = ("SELECT sum(valuta) as total FROM users_cash where valuta='".$val['valuta']."'");
     $sth = $pdo->query($sql);
     $total = $sth->fetchAll();
     $sql = ("SELECT * as total FROM users_cash where valuta='".$val['valuta']."'");
     $sth = $pdo->query($sql);
     $rows = $sth->fetchAll();

     foreach($rows as $row) {
         echo "<p>".$row['name']." ".$row['surname']." ".$row['val']." ".$row['summ']."<p>";
     }
     echo "<p>".$total['total']."<p>";
     }
   ```

Код примерный, так как нет структуры БД. Если что поправите названия полей.

Comment: перед вами пример того, как не надо писать код. На ресурсе довольно часты вопросы "поглядите на мой код, почему он такой медленный", где в ответах пишут "потому что вы выполняете запросы в циклах". Весьма странно, видеть это в качестве ответов.

Comment: Согласен. 15 запров с union эффективнее.

Comment: почему 15? `select  * from users union select null, ...., sum(val) from users group by val` можно разделить на два запроса, и вытащить отдельно суммы, отдельно данные. Но в любом случае для этого не надо на каждую валюту писать запрос.